# Error while doing ng Prod build for angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I have a angular2 project, whenever I try to serve the project or build it, it works fine (creates a dist folder for the ng build command), but whenever I try to build the same project with prod tag turned on (ng build --prod), the compilation fails with a lot of similar error(**Property 'XXX' does not exist**) like below,

```
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/Latest/ang-project/ui/src/app/components/full-
header/full-header.component.html (12,22): Property 'Test' does not exist on typ
e 'FullHeaderComponent'.
```

I seem to remember that the prod flag makes use of `aot` compilation internally - is it so?

If it does use `aot`, should I be enabling the `AOT` in my project(And if yes how should I be doing it?)

Answer (score 4):

`--prod` indeed uses aot compilation.

```
  Flag                    --dev       --prod
--aot                       false       true
--environment               dev         prod
--output-hashing            media       all
--sourcemaps                true        false
--extract-css               false       true
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds

Comment: Why may be the reason for the error to appear only in prod build?

Comment: @Vinay Because of AoT. If you build your app in AoT you need to be more strict. The error you are getting is probably a type mismatch. Jit compiler won't break the build for it but aot will.

Comment: Thanks for info..That helped me a lot

Comment: Declare your Test variable like this "Test: any;" and try